# Prove or disprove that if $f$ is continuous function and $A$ is closed, then $\,f[A]$ is closed.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function and $A\subset X$ is a closed set, 
then $f[A]$ is also closed.

I know that if $f[A]$ is closed implies $A$ is closed then $f$ is continuous, but I'm not sure that the converse is true, I can't find a counterexample either.

Comment: Think about the complements. What does it imply about images of open sets?

Comment: Any restrictions on the domain/codomain of the function $f$?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thank you, I deleted. But am I right in saying that the OP is wrong in saying that 'if $f(A)$ is closed implies $A$ is closed then $f$ is continuous..'? I am still puzzling about a counterexample.

Comment: @drhab, most likely the OP was confused there, but I could not immediately think of a counterexample either. It might be true...

Comment: You are saying that property $f(A)$ closed $\rightarrow A$ closed implies that $f$ is continuous. This is not true. For counterexamples see the answers on question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/688320/75923

Comment: @CarstenSchultz If you are still interested. For counterexamples see the answer to my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/688320/75923

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is NOT true in general.

For example, let $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, with
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{x},
$$
which is continuous, and let $A=(-\infty,0]$, which is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, in its usual topology.

However, $\,\,f[A]=(0,1]$, which is not closed.

Answer (score 7):

Another, and perhaps simpler, counterexample is
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}:\overbrace{[0,\infty)}^{\text{closed}}\mapsto\overbrace{[0,1)}^{\text{not closed}}
$$
You'll notice that all the counterexamples consist of unbounded domains. A closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, and it *is* true that if $f$ is continuous and $A$ is compact, then $f(A)$ is compact, which is also closed.

Answer (score 3):

$$\arctan:\mathbb R\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\text{ is surjective.}$$