# Is this property sufficient for function $f$ to be continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a
map having the property that for each $A\subset X$: $$f\left(A\right)\text{ closed}\Rightarrow A\text{ closed}$$Can it be concluded from this that $f$ is continuous? I encountered this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687411/75923)
and thought immediately: 'no, this is not true'. However, my search
for a counterexample is fruitless uptil now.

Thanks in advance if
you can help me with a proof or counterexample.

Comment: $f(A)$ closed and $f$ continuous implies $\rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(f(A))$ closed. The question is equivalent to is  $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$.  Is this always true for continuous functions?

Comment: @Amy $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ for every $A\subset X$ is true if and only if $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a counterexample. Let $X = \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$, and $Y = [0,1]$ as natural subspaces of the real line.

Define $f:X \to Y$ by

- $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$;
- $f(0) = 1$.

This function is clearly not continuous. ($f^{-1} [\,(\frac{1}{2},1]\,] = \{ 0 , 1 \}$ is not an open subset of $X$.)

Suppose that $A \subseteq X$ is such that $f [ A ]$ is closed in $Y$.  It follows that $A$ must be a finite subset of $X$ (since otherwise $f[A]$ would have $0$ as a limit point, and $0$ is not in the range of $f$), and so $A$ is closed in $X$.

---

Note that if $f[X] = \operatorname{ran}(f)$ were a closed subset of $Y$, then such a function $f$ would be continuous.  This is because for any $B \subseteq Y$ we have $f [ f^{-1} [ B ] ] = B \cap \operatorname{ran}(f)$, and so if $E \subseteq Y$ were closed, then $f [ f^{-1} [ E ] ]$ would also be closed in $Y$, meaning that $f^{-1} [ E ]$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Thank you. I allready was aware of it that surjectivity of $f$ would make it work. This makes it more general.